# How to show full-screen button on embedded Vimeo player on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, embed, fullscreen, mobile-browser, vimeo-player

[image]

Even on the vimeo website, it doesn't show full-screen button with iPhone 4 simulation on Chrome.

It seems like if the screen is small, Vimeo player becomes "Tiny mode" and hides most of components except few.

Is there any way to force the player to display full-screen button? like full-screen-button: true?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not possible, but also not necessary since playback always happens in full screen.

Comment: hmmm, the playback happens in full screen on iOS only though. On android device, for example Nexus 5, will just run the video in the web-app without making it in to full screen.